# I've only made it to here?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

Let's say I'm driving a long way home from work and have lost track of where I am in relation to home. I suddenly notice the exit sign for the city of Van Nuys, which is 45 minutes from home. I get surprised because I thought I've driven a lot farther and should've been much closer to home. Are these idiomatic to say?

```
"I'm only at Van Nuys?!"

"I've only hit it this far?!"

"I've only made it this far?!"

"I've only made/hit it to Van Nuys?!"

"I've only made it as far as Van Nuys?!"

"I've only come this far?!"
```

Is there another more common saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phrases

> I'm only at Van Nuys.
>   I've only made it to Van Nuys.
>   I've only made it as far as Van Nuys.
>   I've only hit Van Nuys.

are idiomatic for talking to someone on the phone telling them where you are

> I've only come this far?

is idiomatic when asking the rhetorical question

There is also

> Q: Where are you?
>   A: I got to Van Nuys *(so far)*.